# How can I rewrite an average value per date time interval MySQL query as a Django QuerySet?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, django-mysql

I have the following MySQL query that displays the average value per 10 minute interval:

```sql
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_time) / 600) * 600) AS interval_date_time,
AVG(some_value) AS avg_value
FROM djangoapp_somemodel
GROUP BY interval_date_time
ORDER BY interval_date_time;
```

For example, if I have the following 3 records:

| item_id | date_time | some_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-11-29 00:11:01 | 10 |
| 2 | 2021-11-29 00:16:15 | 20 |
| 3 | 2021-11-29 00:24:32 | 25 |

The query will output the following:

| interval_date_time | avg_value |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-11-29 00:10:00 | 15 |
| 2021-11-29 00:20:00 | 25 |

I suspect the query isn't that efficient but I want to get the same output using a Django QuerySet.

For reference, my Django model looks like this:

```py
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    item_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    some_value = models.FloatField()
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Here's my current QuerySet:

```py
(SomeModel.objects
    .annotate(interval_date_time=F("date_time"))
    .values("interval_date_time")
    .annotate(avg_value=Avg("some_value"))
    .order_by("interval_date_time")
)
```

I believe I need to make changes to the first annotate method call. Any help would be appreciated as I am quite new to Django.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be easiest to just use [`RawSQL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.expressions.RawSQL) here if you know you'll always be working with MySQL.

```
(
    SomeModel.objects.annotate(interval_date_time=RawSQL("FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_time) / 600) * 600)", ()))
    .values("interval_date_time")
    .annotate(avg_value=Avg("some_value"))
    .order_by("interval_date_time")
)
```

Comment: This works for now, thank you. I had to change the RawSQL to `RawSQL("FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_time) / 600) * 600)", ())` (added empty params) for it to work.

Comment: Ah, yeah, good catch! Edited that in to the answer too. :)